# OutputCache attribute always has the previous duration set

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, outputcache

For some reason the output cache keeps the two week duration I apply to an expired event, on an event in the future.  Am I missing something in my custom output provider to stop the saving of the duration?

```
[ExpiredOutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "eventid;expired")]
        public virtual ActionResult GetDivisionsViews(int eventId, EventDivisionsViewModel viewModel)
        {

}

    public class ExpiredOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
        {
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                if((filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[Config.QueryString.Expired] != null && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[Config.QueryString.Expired].To<DateTime>().Date < DateTime.Now.Date.Date) || 
                   (filterContext.RouteData.Values[Config.QueryString.Expired] != null && filterContext.RouteData.Values[Config.QueryString.Expired].To<DateTime>().Date < DateTime.Now.Date.Date))
                {
                    Duration = (int)Config.Cache.TwoWeeks * 60;
                }

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's because asp.net caches action attribute instances. So you are updating Duration of the same attribute instance, which is then reused by subsequent requests.

Comment: thanks but is there a solution?

Comment: Easiest would be to set Duration in else block to whatever value you need (to 3600 I guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this.

```
protected int OriginalDuration { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if(OriginalDuration == 0)
            {
                OriginalDuration = Duration;
            }

            if ((filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[Config.QueryString.Expired] != null && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[Config.QueryString.Expired].To<DateTime>().Date < DateTime.Now.Date.Date) || 
               (filterContext.RouteData.Values[Config.QueryString.Expired] != null && filterContext.RouteData.Values[Config.QueryString.Expired].To<DateTime>().Date < DateTime.Now.Date.Date))
            {
                Duration = (int)Config.Cache.TwoWeeks * 60;
            }
            else
            {
                Duration = OriginalDuration;
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```